# GSM шлюз между android устройствами по локалке

Tags: android

Имеется задача из android устройств по локалке сделать gsm шлюз. Т.е. при совершении звонка с устройства №1 оно выбирает в локалке любую доступную сим-карту. Реально ли? Что посоветуете почитать? Спасибо!